# Mosquitto broker ACL list over bridge

Tags: ssl, mqtt, acl, mosquitto

First let me explain what I'm trying to do.

We have a SAAS environment which has a mosquitto broker installed. This environment hosts several of our customers.

Each and every customer has their own VM also containing a mosquitto broker. This broker on the customer's environment is bridged to our SAAS environment's broker using the following config.

```
connection bridgeconnection
address 184.168.0.5:1883
topic test1/testing/customer1 out 2
topic test2/testing/customer1 in 2
remote_clientid remote.test123
remote_username user1
remote_password 321
```

It is very important that we don't let one customer write or read the topics of another customer. So, we are planning on making use of ACL lists for every customer.

On the SAAS environment, we have a password.txt file that contains entries like this:

```
admin:1234(The password part here is actually hashed in the actual file)
user1:321(Even this password is hashed as it was added using the mosquitto_passswd.exe)
```

We also have a acl.txt file on our SAAS environment. The contents of this file are:

```
user user1
topic test1/testing/customer1 write
topic test2/testing/customer1 read
```

The broker config on the SAAS environment has the following properties set correctly.

```
password_file C:\mosquitto\pw_file.txt
allow_anonymous false
acl_file C:\mosquitto\acl.txt
```

After restarting both the customer's broker as well as the SAAS broker I am expecting to not be able to write or read any other topics other than the ones I have given access to for this customer in the ACL file. However, I am still able to write as well as read all topics present on my SAAS broker from my remote broker.

Another issue that I seem to be facing is in the bridge config itself. As per my bridge, I am allowing the read of one topic and write of another topic. However, regardless of the read topic being explicitly specified, I am still able to read all the topics that are present on my SAAS broker from my remote(customer's) broker.

All of this is being tested on 2 Windows 10 server running mosquitto broker version 2.0.9a X64.

Please let me know if there is something wrong I am doing with the configuration over here.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are actually testing this

Comment: Hi @hardillb. I got this to work for me now. Went through the man page and tried to do this step by step. Like first successfully established the bridge, then acl. To test this, I used the mqttexplorer. On sending messages to topics not specified in the acl file, the remote broker doesn't receive the messages. Thanks for the reply though